# Updating value in viewmodel from bluetooth characteristic

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I use the Xabre BLE library for Xamarin studio. Within my project, I have a bluetooth class, and a ViewModel.

When my app connects to a specified characteristic, I subscribe to a `characteristic.ValueUpdated` event, from which I update a value in my viewmodel.

In my viewmodel, I have a propertychanged eventhandler, which listens to updates from the bluetooth class.

For some reason however, the setter is not updating my value

Bluetooth class:

```
public class Bluetooth 
{
//code to respectively connect and disconnect 

    public async void GetValuesFromCharacteristic()
    {
        CarouselViewModel viewModel = new CarouselViewModel();
        Characteristic.ValueUpdated += (s, a) =>
        {
            viewModel.CurrentValue = Characteristic.Value[7].ToString();
        };
        await Characteristic.StartUpdatesAsync();
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CarouselViewModel
{
    private _currentValue;
    public CarouselViewModel()
    {

    }

    public string CurrentValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_currentValue != value)
            {
                _currentValue = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(_currentValue));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You Bluetooth class is creating an instance of the ViewModel.  Does the page also have it's own instance?  If you have multiple instances of your VM changes to one will not be reflected in the others.  Secondly, have you traced the execution in the debugger to verify that your events and setters are actually being called?

Comment: the page has an instance too yes. But my setter is actually being updated! The problem is though, that when put a breakpoint in my setter, my application breaks and tells me that "No compatible code running" - "The selected debug engine does not support any code executing on the current thread (e.g. only native runtime code is executing)"

Comment: I'd assume your root problem is that you have multiple copies of the VM and are not updating the "correct" one.

Comment: instead of constructing my viewmodel in the bluetooth class, would you suggest i should do something else?

Comment: I'd suggest that your BT class should raise events or messages when it receives data of interest.  Then your VM can subscribe to those events/messages.